# Special character are getting encrypted while passing through API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Global weather API .

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("success1");

            $('#ClickData').click(function () {
                var CountryDetails = "524901&APPID=3a93f181f74c615547db27a418662aa4";
                //$('#TextCountry').val()
                var Pdata = $('#DataArea').val();
                alert(CountryDetails);
                $.ajax({
                    //524901&APPID=e962f6f0d29167e22903aaa90e72203f
                    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: { id: CountryDetails },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:
                        function (Final)
                        {
                            if (Final.weather[0].message != null)
                            {
                                Pdata.html(Final.weather[0].message);
                                alert("success3");
                            }
                                //alert("success");
                            else
                            {
                                alert("success5");
                                Pdata.html(Final.weather[0].main + '<br\>' + Final.weather[0].description);
                            }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Country <input type="text" id="TextCountry" />
    <input type="button" value="Click" id="ClickData" /><br /><br />

    <p id="DataArea"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am passing the appkey ID (which is required to get access to the web API.. Here the issue is I am passing "**http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=3a93f181f74c615547db27a418662aa4**" data to the APi where as while calling the Special character like '&' & '=' are getting encrypted like this "**http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901%26APPID%3D3a93f181f74c615547db27a418662aa4**"

Please help me in this regard how to handle  this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX request is seeing only one parameter `id` and escaping the characters that have special meaning, `=` and `&`. You need to pass the query parameters separately.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city',
    method: 'get',
    data: {
        id: '524901',
        APPID: 'e962f6f0d29167e22903aaa90e72203'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it resolves your issue? Thanks